# Network status is always true for android. How?

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I'm trying to check the network status in my android application.

And I have code like this:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This code is returning `true` when network is available as expected but it is also returing `true` even in case of network not-available.

Simply put its returning `true` for both the cases!

Where I'm making the mistake in the code?

Note that I run the app in my emulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you try this code in the device as well, because in emulator some of such stuff is not very reliable, as they are mainly simulated onces.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below method it works awesome for me. I hope it will help you also.

> ```
>  public static boolean IsNetConnected()
> {
>     boolean NetConnected = false;
>     try
>     {
>         ConnectivityManager connectivity =
>         (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>         if (connectivity == null)
>         {
>             NetConnected = false;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
>             if (info != null)
>             {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
>                 {
>                     if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
>                     {
>                         NetConnected = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         NetConnected = false;
>     }
>     return NetConnected;
> }
> ```