# Network status always returns true for isConnected() and isConnectedOrConnecting()

Tags: java, android, networking, android-emulator, android-networking

My app needs to know whether it has internet access or not. I tried to follow best practice as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009133/7575056
However, the following method always returns true:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

A similar question has been asked before at
[Network status is always true for android. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577181/network-status-is-always-true-for-android-how)
Yet, suggested solution uses deprecated methods and should not be the solution anyway I suppose.

I'm running the code on an emulator that runs on my developer machine (my laptop), and I'm testing my code using several conditions:

- disable WIFI on laptop (and no cable)
- enable flight mode on laptop
- use `adb shell svc wifi enable / disable` to work with the emulator directly

No matter what I do, it always returns true and gives me a timeout when I actually try to connect to a www resource (so there is no magic internet connection indeed):

```
String searchResultsStr = IOUtils.toString(url.openStream());
```

Advice anyone?